# Can glucose and insulin exist in the same container without reacting?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, biochemistry, proteins

Someone asked if glucose and insulin could be mixed in the same container and used as an injection to provide a quick energy boost. I'm not interested about the medical part of this question, but just if glucose and insulin (which is a protein) could exist in the same container without reacting with each other without forming some sort of glycoprotein. Is it possible to make a reasonable prediction what would/not happen in the mixed glucose/insulin solution in the container?

I know that insulin and glucose do not react with in the body, I want to know if in aqueous solution they would react.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glycoproteins come in O-linked and N-linked forms. For O-linked sugars, a glycosidic bond forms between the sugar and the hydroxyl of a serine or threonine side chain. For N-linked sugars, a glycosidic bond forms between the sugar and the amide of asparagine. The equilibrium for all these reactions lies on the side of hydrolysis in aqueous solution.

> Is it possible to make a reasonable prediction what would/not happen in the mixed glucose/insulin solution in the container?

Yes, in aqueous solution there is no expectation that a glycoprotein forms between insulin and glucose. In vivo, glycoproteins form in a coupled reaction involving the carbohydrate (usually an oligosaccharide rather than a single glucose), the protein and a nucleotide triphosphate.

However, if an individual has high blood sugar levels (i.e. high concentrations of glucose in the blood) for extended periods of time, hemoglobin (specifically, the N-terminal amino group and the sidechain amino group of lysine) will react with the sugar and become [glycalated](http://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/HbA1c_test_for_diabetes). This is used in the HbA1c diagnostic test for checking if someone has diabetes. After the sugar binds (reversibly), there is a further reaction ([Amadori rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadori_rearrangement)) that leads to a long-lasting product.

Comment: OK. Is there any enzyme required for the formation of glycoproteins _in vitro_ ?

Comment: It would not form because the equilibrium lies on the side of the reactants.